# How do I make Facebook comments public for all on my website?

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I've added facebook comments to my website using the following steps:

I created a new app herehttps://developers.facebook.com/apps/
In the auth dialog page for the app, I set 'default activity privacy' to 'Public'

I got the code for the comments box here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

I used the HTML5 version of the code and added it to my site in the two places specified - right after the body tag and where I want the comments to appear.

I then opened the comments moderation tool for my new app.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=recent_comments
I clicked on 'Settings' and turned on 'Make every post public by default'
I also listed myself as a moderator.

I also added

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">
```

inside the head tags for the page.

When I go to my site - the comments box appears to work ok. I can make a comment, but I can only see comments made by me.  I cannot see comments made by people I am not friends with.  How do I fix this problem? I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, i have same problem. You solved it?

Comment: Me too have same problem... how you solved it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every comment you leave on a facebook-comments driven web site is public, the same way it is on a fan page. Even a non facebook member can leave a comment.

I am looking for a way to turn it off and get the same permissions you have on your facebook wall. Currently, everybody who has the link can see the page content and all previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and figured out that Facebook grabs urls differently for displaying and submiting comments.

If the url you're providing him in data-href (e.g. short url) is different than the window.location url (url in address bar), then it's probably the case.

P.S. I know that the question is from 2011, but someone else may show up with the same problem.